# How to pass data 'over' a ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

My app has an `AuthenticationViewController` which allows users the authenticate with TouchID and then, once approved, are shown a list of banking transactions (the two are linked with a segue, which is shown once approved).

Now I've added the ability to import a custom file type - a Transaction - into the app. This is working well and loads a vc called `ImportTransactionViewController` using `application(_:open:options:)` when the user opens the file.

What's the best way to pass this imported transaction 'through' my `AuthenticationViewController` so that when the user is approved, the `ImportTransactionViewController` loads with my imported transaction.

In summary, I currently have:

> AuthenticationViewController -> User approved -> TransactionsViewController

but I also want to be able to do:

> User selects Transaction file to import -> AuthenticationViewController (storing the Transaction to pass on to next vc if approved) -> User approved -> ImportedTransactionViewController (showing the Transaction that was 'passed through' the AuthenticationViewController).

Any suggestions on the tidiest, clearest way to achieve this would be much appreciated.

Comment: To me it seems the most obvious solution to this would be to divorce the data from the ViewControllers. Save them in a singleton when you want to keep them while the app is active, or just use a database model.

Save what you need to the model class, e.g `DatabaseManager` in your `ImportTransactionsViewController`. Then, in `TransactionsViewController`, load the data from `DatabaseManager`.

Comment: Agree Singleton is the best approach here.

Comment: Thanks for your replies @TomQDRS and Brandon - I'll look into that approach.